# jQuery Form Plugin: enctype:multipart/form-data and file-upload - no JSON returning?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, file-upload, jquery-forms-plugin

weird problem or bug. I'm using the [jQuery Form Plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/) and it works fine everywhere accept on one form where I have a single file-upload with `enctype:multipart/form-data` on the form. On this form I'm facing two weird things …

1. the JSON object that is returned from the server is empty!
2. In Opera the Submit-button even triggers a file-download!

However this occurs only if I leave the `enctype:multipart/form-data` and the `input type="file"` in the form. Without it everything works fine and the JSON Object is returned correctly - and there is no download in Opera.

HTML:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/ajax/profiledetails" id="profileAboutMeForm" method="post" novalidate="novalidate" encoding="multipart/form-data" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    ...

    <p class="rel avatarUpload">
        <label class="label" for="profileAvatar">Choose Avatar</label>
        <img class="profileAvatar avatar30" src="" alt="user">
        <input class="fileUpload br3" id="profileAvatar" name="profile[avatar]" type="file">
    </p>

    ...

</form>
```

jQuery:

```
$(formId).ajaxSubmit({
        type: "POST",
        cache: false,
        resetForm: reset,
        dataType: "text json",
        success: function(jsonObject, status) {

            console.log("status + ", jsonObject.status: "+ jsonObject.status + ", jsonObject.data: " + jsonObject.data);
```

Any idea what could cause that? How I could fix that?

Thank's in advance.

**edit:**

What I never tried though was to just log the object itself and here it turns out that in this case (only if the file-input and enctype is set) the jsonObject is a STRING and not an object.

```
if (typeof jsonObject == 'string')
        console.log('yes, it's a string'); //yes, it's a string
        jsonObject = JSON.parse(jsonObject);

console.log(jsonObject);
```

So, this means I have a JSObject again in my javascript and this fixes my first problem, however the opera-bug still remains! Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as a starting point, I assume you've read the documentation about this on the plugins page at http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#file-upload? You won't get access to the JSON within ajaxSubmit() because the response is actually written to a hidden iframe used for the upload.

> "Since it is not possible to upload files using the browser's
>   XMLHttpRequest object, the Form Plugin uses a hidden iframe element to
>   help with the task. This is a common technique, but it has inherent
>   limitations. The iframe element is used as the target of the form's
>   submit operation which means that the server response is written to
>   the iframe. This is fine if the response type is HTML or XML, but
>   doesn't work as well if the response type is script or JSON, both of
>   which often contain characters that need to be repesented using entity
>   references when found in HTML markup.
>
> To account for the challenges of script and JSON responses, the Form
>   Plugin allows these responses to be embedded in a textarea element and
>   it is recommended that you do so for these response types when used in
>   conjuction with file uploads. Please note, however, that if there is
>   no file input in the form then the request uses normal XHR to submit
>   the form (not an iframe). This puts the burden on your server code to
>   know when to use a textarea and when not to. If you like, you can use
>   the iframe option of the plugin to force it to always use an iframe
>   mode and then your server can always embed the response in a textarea."

Here is the code he uses on the examples page:

```
$('#uploadForm').ajaxForm({
  beforeSubmit: function(a,f,o) {
    o.dataType = $('#uploadResponseType')[0].value;
    $('#uploadOutput').html('Submitting...');
  },
  success: function(data) {
    var $out = $('#uploadOutput');
    $out.html('Form success handler received: <strong>' + typeof data + '</strong>');
    if (typeof data == 'object' && data.nodeType)
      data = elementToString(data.documentElement, true);
    else if (typeof data == 'object')
      data = objToString(data);
    $out.append('<div><pre>'+ data +'</pre></div>');
  }
});
```

The `success` method is what matters for you here...notice that he is writing the return `data` to the page for debugging purposes.

Comment: Well, first of all, thank you for your answer. I read me through the js file of the documentation where you posted the little snippet above. And after a while playing with this stuff and even implementing the two helper functions objToString and elementToString I found that actually none of these functions are getting fired because the jsonObject is not an object but a STRING. I updated my question so you can see what I mean. What I do now is convert it back to a JSObject so my question 1 is solved. However, still the download in opera persists! Any ideas?

Comment: Ok, it's probably a bug! The solution is that the server has to respond with a content-type of HTML and not JSON! With html everything works just fine!